# Does using same AzureSasCredential object in many clients result in updating all clients if I update the sas token?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-.net

I am using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus .net sdk for my project. If I use 5 different ServiceBusClient objects but use the same AzureSasCredential object while creating the above-said clients, and I update the AzureSasCredential object with ".Update(newSasToken), does it apply to all 5 clients and have their validity updated? I am of the understanding that any operation using the clients thereafter will present the new SasToken that was updated and will work with a new token validity. Please clarify.

On another note, if the clients are not used to send/receive for a long time(a few hours) after a bout of send/receive operations, will their connections go to "sleep" under the hood or will they still be counted as "Active Connection" on my Service Bus namespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  When you pass the `AzureSasCredential` to a client, the client holds that reference.  When `Update` is called, the new token value will be available to anyone with a reference.  In the case of a `SerivceBusClient`, the new token will be sent the next time that authorization is renewed.

Connections have an idle timeout on the client side (60 seconds by default) and on the service-side (currently 30 minutes, but may change).  At some point after one of those timeouts is exceeded, within a small window of non-determinism, the connection will be closed ad no longer counted against your limit.  The client will recreate the connection for the next service operation that is requested.